# Versioning: Possible to remove list elements in WCF DataContract serialization?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, serialization, collections

Suppose I have the following code:

```
namespace Test
{
    [DataContract()]
    internal class Class2 : AbstractSerializeableObject
    {
        [DataMember()]
        int[] ints;

        protected override XMLVersion ObjectVersion
        {
            get { return version; }
        }
        [DataMember()]
        private XMLVersion version = new XMLVersion(1, 0, 0, "Test");

        protected override void SetDefaults()
        {
            ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        }
    }
}
```

Which ultimately serializes into the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Class2 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test">
    <ints xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <d2p1:int>1</d2p1:int>
        <d2p1:int>2</d2p1:int>
        <d2p1:int>3</d2p1:int>
        <d2p1:int>4</d2p1:int>
    </ints>
    <version xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XMLSerializationLib">
        <d2p1:description></d2p1:description>
        <d2p1:major>1</d2p1:major>
        <d2p1:minor>0</d2p1:minor>
        <d2p1:patch>0</d2p1:patch>
        <d2p1:title>Test</d2p1:title>
    </version>
</Class2>
```

Now I would like to remove a couple elements from my `ints` array. My `AbstractSerializeableObject` is designed so that `SetDefaults` is called upon serialization or when the constructor is called (in the same fashion as the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160106/set-default-value-in-a-datacontract)) The problem is that the DataContractSerializer reads in the contents of the entire collection (regardless of how many elements are in the default array). So if there are 4 elements in the XML and 2 in my default values list, there will be 4 elements in my deserialized array.

Is there any way I can fix the size of the collection so that the extra values in the XML file are omitted upon deserialization?

Comment: You can't change the size of an array. Why not use a List<int>?

Comment: That's not the issue; I'll have the same problem if I use a list, array, or even dictionary; really any Collection.

Comment: Suppose I initialize the array with 5 elements in my first version of the DataContract. Then suppose I make a revision to the contract and instead initialize it with just 3 elements. When the XML file from the previous contract is deserialized with the new contract, it pulls in 5 elements and not 3.

Answer (score 0):

This type of scenario should be well suited for the use of [Data Contract Surrogates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The data contract surrogate is an advanced feature built upon the Data
>   Contract model. This feature is designed to be used for type
>   customization and substitution in situations where users want to
>   change how a type is serialized, deserialized or projected into
>   metadata. Some scenarios where a surrogate may be used is when a data
>   contract has not been specified for the type, fields and properties
>   are not marked with the DataMemberAttribute attribute or users wish to
>   dynamically create schema variations.
>
> Serialization and deserialization are accomplished with the data
>   contract surrogate when using DataContractSerializer to convert from
>   .NET Framework to a suitable format, such as XML. Data contract
>   surrogate can also be used to modify the metadata exported for types,
>   when producing metadata representations such as XML Schema Documents
>   (XSD). Upon import, code is created from metadata and the surrogate
>   can be used in this case to customize the generated code as well.

For example, in your case
 to make it so that only 2 elements are included in the serialized XML:

```
public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetObjectToSerialize");
    if (obj is Class2)
    {
        Class2Surrogated c2sur = new Class2Surrogated();
        c2sur.ints = ((Class2Surrogated)obj).ints.Take(2).ToArray();
        c2sur.version = ((Class2Surrogated)obj).version;
        return c2sur;
    }
    return obj;
}
```