# Set default values of a DataContract/serialization class's attributes

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datacontract

I have a serialization class which 'interprets' a json file, everything is brilliant when the json has all the possible objects and keys etc.

When the serialation can not find a specific json key it defaults the value of the missing variable/attribute to 0 for integers, null for strings and false for bools.

I want to be able to set my own default eg -1 for a integer so that if a variable is not init'd during deserialisation it has a expected value.

Here is an example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace exampleSerialiser
{
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(exampleSerialiser))]
    public class exampleSerialiser
    {
        [DataMember]
        [DefaultValue("whyIsThisNotSet")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool ison{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Example Json (empty)

> {
>
> }

resulting variable values

> id=""
>   ison=false

Desired values

> id="valueNotSetHere"
>   ison=true

Comment: From [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code."

Comment: I tried but I get syntax errors as im not sure where to do this among my get; set; etc. Can you show me using my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default value in a DataContract?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160106/set-default-value-in-a-datacontract)

Comment: thats it stuartd - is this the best way to do this, seems an obvious candidate for some native methods in .net to allow this. it all seems very regid and loses its appeal when json doesn't match exactly what i want in my class or if i want to insert logic.

Comment: stuartd add ur answer